# Установка npm модуля в проект

Tags: node.js, windows

У меня есть проект по такому адресу:

```
F:\development\WebStormProjects\test-app
```

Как мне установить туда npm модуль?
Для примера (`npm install twitter-bootstrap-node`)

У меня OS Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F:
cd development\WebStormProjects\test-app
npm install ....
```

Comment: а как мне на командной строке перйти на F ? (у меня windows)

Comment: Используйте

    cd F:

Comment: cd /D F: все нашел спасибо

Comment: @Niki-Timofe, можно и без cd :)